# How to switch arithmetric operations in a String

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I have a problem when trying to switch the signs of all arithmetic operations inside a string in Python.

My input looks like this: `"+1-2"`

And the output should be something like that: `"-1+2"`

But when I try to replace the characters with `replace()` function:

```
"+1-2".replace("+", "-").replace("-", "+")
```

The output I get is that: `'+1+2'`

Looks like the `replace` functions are replacing everything at the same time, so it will never switch it correctly in that way. A one-liner solution with similar functions would be very helpful.

Comment: Use a dummy character for the intermediate step: `"+1-2".replace("+","!").replace("-","+").replace("!","-")`

Comment: Indeed, replacing one thing with another and then replacing the other thing with the first will turn all instances into the first. You want `translate` instead.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, I didn't know that function for replacing characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.translate`:

```py
s = "+1-2+3+4-2-1"
t = str.maketrans('+-','-+')
print(s.translate(t))
```

Output:

```
-1+2-3-4+2+1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I didn't know the `translate()` function for `strings`, now it's working perfectly.